# Trying to edit file in vi and it crashes [1]+ Stopped

Tags: linux, centos, vi

Found this question, this is what I see:
[Swap file error message while trying to edit .vimrc file?](https://superuser.com/questions/543354/swap-file-error-message-while-trying-to-edit-vimrc-file)

But in my case, I can delete swap files, try to edit file and Ctrl-Z and I get this:

```
[6]+  Stopped                 vi /etc/xinetd.d/tftp
[root@localhost ~]# vi  /etc/xinetd.d/tftp 

[7]+  Stopped                 vi /etc/xinetd.d/tftp
[root@localhost ~]#
```

So, for some reason something doesn't let me save this config file. I'm new to Linux and use vi for all config files (and this one as well) but I see this first time. Just won't save - keep giving [x]+ Stopped errors.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is perfectly normal behaviour (i.e. *not* an error) in `bash` in similar shells: Ctrl-Z suspends programs and returns control to the parent shell. Execution of the program -- `vi` in your case -- will be stopped in the mean time. You can type `fg` to resume execution.

The reason you are getting swap file errors is because you now have multiple instances of `vi` simultaneously editing the same file; the entire purpose of the swap files is to bring such scenarios to your attention, because it's almost never what you want to happen.

Since it looks like you have a whole bunch of `vi` instances open (7 of them -- that's what the [7]+ indicates), it's probably best to just close them normally one by one: type `fg` to bring up the last instance and then press Escape and type `:q!` to close it normally. Repeat until `fg` says "no such job". Then remove any swapfiles that may still exist (`rm /etc/xinetd.d/.tftp.sw*`), and open the file again. In `vi`, the command to write and quit a file is Escape + `:wq`. The command to undo a change (which my gut tells me is probably why you were pressing Ctrl-Z) is Escape + `u`.

`vi` is a so-called *modal editor*: in *normal mode* (which is accessed by pressing Escape), single keys are mapped to commands. In *insert mode* (accessed by pressing `i` or `a` in normal mode), you can insert text. For more information, see e.g. [this quick guide](http://www.astrohandbook.com/ch20/vi_guide.html).

Comment: This is universal and not limited to `vi`: https://www.cyberciti.biz/faq/unix-linux-fg-command-examples-usage-syntax/